# Правильная работа else в forech

Tags: php, массивы, if

При указании условия esle в цикле выводится не 1 значение переменной, а зацикленное значение.
Массив вида:

```
[
{
    "user": "Петров Иван",
    "Department": "1",
    "Total": 9688,
    "Addon_1": "1",
    "Addon_2": "2",
    "Addon_3": "3",
    "topuser": "4"
},
{       "user": "Иванов Петр",
    "Department": "1",
    "Total": 9688,
    "Addon_1": "1",
    "Addon_2": "2",
    "Addon_3": "3",
    "topuser": "4"
}
```

]

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);
$a = "Петров Иван";
<?php
foreach ($arr as $row) { 
    if($row['user'] == $a)
        echo $row['user'];
    else {
        echo $a;
    }
}
?>
```

Как правильно вывести если "user" в массиве = $a вывести "user" из массива, если такое значение не найдено вывести переменную $a.

Comment: Для начала надо собраться с мыслями, и *внятно* объяснить исходную задачу. Причем совсем исходную. Я сильно подозреваю, что никакого цикла тут вообще не должно быть, а БД должна сразу возвращать одну-единственную строку.

Comment: Имеется ассоциативный массив $arr в котором есть параметр 'user'. Я пытаюсь сделать проверку Если переменная $a = есть в массиве в параметре  'user' выводить данный параметр, иначе вывести значение переменной $a.

Comment: начнем с того, что массив $arr никакой не ассоциативный.

Comment: Сколько в массиве элементов  - столько выводов и получили.

Comment: `[
 {
  "user": "Петров Иван",
  "Department": "1",
  "Total": 9688,
  "Addon_1": "1",
  "Addon_2": "2",
  "Addon_3": "3",
  "topuser": "4"
 },
 {  "user": "Иванов Петр",
  "Department": "1",
  "Total": 9688,
  "Addon_1": "1",
  "Addon_2": "2",
  "Addon_3": "3",
  "topuser": "4"
 }
]` 

Массив такого вида.
$arr = json_decode($response, true);
$a = "Петров Иван";

Каким образом мне тогда выводить проверку?
Если "user" == $a выводить "user" иначе выводить $a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приблизительный алгоритм может быть таким:

```
$userFound = false;    // флаг, сообщающий что пользователь найден 
foreach ($arr as $row) { 
    if($row['user'] == $a)
        $userFound = true;  
        echo $row['user'];
        break;         // прерываем цикл, так как дальнейшие элементы нас не интересуют
    }
}
// так как пользователь НЕ найден - выводим что-то еще.
if (!$userFound) {
    echo $a;
}
```